# Users can choose image style on content type?

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I want to display image style list in particular content type. Users can choose their image style from the list provided.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully I've understood you properly; I think you're looking for the [Formatter Field](http://drupal.org/project/formatter_field) module:

> The formatter field module provides a mechanism for specifying a formatter and formatter settings to be used for displaying a field, on a per-entity basis. By default, Drupal provides formatters and settings per entity bundle, but in certain situations it is necessary to choose the formatter at the entity level.
>
> For example, say you have a page node with an image field. Normally, you would select an image style as the formatter, and all page nodes would use that same image style. With this module, you can add a formatter field to page nodes, which is hooked up to the image field. Then when the node is created or edited, the image style can be selected per-node.

Comment: The Formatter Field is a generic solution, which allows to change the formatter field of any field type (not only the Image fields). However, as a consequence the list of image styles to select from cannot be limited (as asked in the question)..

Answer (score 3):

If you want an user to select an image style when he/she uploads an image, take a look at the [Image Style Selector](https://www.drupal.org/project/iss) module. The list of image styles that the user can select from is configurable by the website administrator.

The screenshot below shows the (basic) functionality of this module.

[image: The Image Style Selector module provides the functionality to select a predefined image style, which is applied to the (uploaded) image]