# How do I conditionally style an image field based on terms

Tags: 7, views, media

I have a Drupal website with a content type (*Article*) which has a taxonomy term reference field (*Topic*) for the *Topics* vocabulary.

The *Article* path aliases, based on the taxonomy term are, for example, the following one.

- /books/100-days-around-the-world
- /culture/chinese-and-medicine

The content type has also an image field (*Image*). I want to style the main image for the articles classified under *books* differently; I want the image to have greater height than width.

The only way I could think to achieve that is creating a new view for it. I tried to create it, but it only rendered the first article of books. The following screenshot shows the view settings.

> [image: screenshot]

The real problem is that I don't know a view that renders the article content page. When I contacted the theme author], for previous modification requests, I was told to use the node--article.tpl.php template file. So I have only two ways:

1. Create a view that renders articles as I described earlier
2. Write code in the node--article.tpl.php template file that conditionally set a style for the image field when the article topic term is *books*

I don't know how to get what I need using the two approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method 1. Use a node preprocessor

Add this to your theme's template.php, then clear the cache:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  
  // This only applies to content type 'article' in teaser view.
  if ($variables['node']->type == 'article' && $variables['view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
     
     // Find out if node has at least one tag and an image.
     if (isset($variables['content']['field_tags']) && isset($variables['content']['field_image'])) {
      
      // Map tags to style names.
      $settings = array(
        'apple' => 'medium', 
        'banana' => 'large',
      );
      
      // Build an array of tag names.
      $tags = array();
      foreach ($variables['content']['field_tags'] as $k => $v) {
        if (is_int($k)) {
          $tags[] = $v['#title'];
        }
      }
      
      // For each mapping, check if the tag exists in the $tags array; 
      // if yes, apply the style.
      foreach ($settings as $tag => $style_name) {
        if (in_array($tag, $tags)) {
          $variables['content']['field_image'][0]['#image_style'] = $style_name;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that we could also do something similar in node--article.tpl.php, but generally you want to keep code logic out of the template files.

---

#### Method 2. Use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Field formatter conditions](https://www.drupal.org/project/ffc) modules (no coding required!)

The example below will set the image style of `field_image` to 'thumbnail' in the node's teaser view if `field_tags` contains a term with an ID of 18.

The *Field formatter conditions* module an image style to be conditionally set based on the outcome of a rule. It involves creating a rule, then going to *Structure > Content types > [content type] > Manage display* and adding the condition in the configuration options of your display (in this case the "Teaser" display).

*Note: This example only checks for a single term. To compare against more terms, add more "List contains item" conditions, one for each term.*

Here is the rule:

[image]

Here are the formatter settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to add/edit the `node--article.tpl.php` (don't forget to flush caches after you have). Once you have done this you can vary the output based on the values in the `$node` object.

[Node template API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7.x)

Comment: The problem, indeed, is not just the render way of an image, the real problem is to access the view or calling the view with an article details page of topic named books!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The problem is that you want the article page to show a different style image when displaying a article node tagged as a 'book'? 
Or you have a problem getting the view to work?

Comment: Yes it is the first. I want the image with different style when the tag is `books`.