# How can I have different image size for a content type

Tags: media

I have 3 type of products that I want to put their image in my site. I have define a content type for them. there is a field that I put the image of my products and I've use imagefield crop module to crop my images but the problem is I don't want any specific ratio for my pictures or at least I have 3 define ratio for my images(each for a product).
I would appreciate if you tell me how can I set the different image size for my product with just one content type?
TNX

Edit:
for example I have chosen the "Image with cropping" as a widget of my field in a content type and because in its option I should fill the blank of the "resolution of cropped image" I set 300x300 like this:

[image]

Then when I crop my product option it gave me this:
for 136x65

[image]

After Cropping

[image]

or for 170x300

[image]

After

[image]

And I should decide whether my image is square size or rectangular ??

Comment: have you tried using image styles

Comment: Yes I can show my content in the view with image style perfectly. but how can I use image style when I define a product.

Comment: you can do that in the manage display. you can choose the image style you want

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71242/users-can-choose-image-style-on-content-type, could you confirm if that's what you're asking for?

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply. @mohammed if I choose the image style in manage display it change the style for all node that has this kind of content type (but I want to have different style in one content type). clive it's not what I want. to make it clear the imagefield crop module can select and crop an image type for each node but it has an option that should be filled (the resolution to crop the image onto) and I want to choose the resolution base on the node or at least the resolution doesn't matter at all.

Comment: You mean automatically select the resolution depending on some fields or properties in the node?

Comment: Not actually I just want to crop my images without defining the resolution or if it's not feasible. I want to pre define some resolution and then when I create note choose one of them? [when I don't define the resolution in  imagefield crop module it force me to define final resolution :(]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Image Style Selector](https://www.drupal.org/project/iss) module allows you to select a predefined image style and apply it to the uploaded image. In this way when you create a node (or any other fieldable entity), upload an image, you can choose which image style to apply to that image.